# Why need to use semicolon before defining a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've seen some strange `;` at the beginning of a function in some jQuery plugins source code like this:

```
;(function ($) {.....
```

Can someone explain why they need to use `;` in this case?

Comment: It's because some people just don't care about the quality of the code they write. Semicolon allows them to add new stuff to their code without paying attention to what's before.

Comment: @lan done. marked it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This semicolon will help you to properly concatenate a new code into a file when the current existed code in this file does not include a `;` at the end.

For example:

```
(function() {

})()  // <--- No semicolon

//  Added semicolon to prevent unexpected laziness result from previous code    
;(function ($) {

})();
```

Without the semicolon, the second `()` would have been interpreted as a function call, and will tried to call the return result of the first function

Comment: I don't think it's a syntax error. It's to prevent the second script from calling the first. `()` calls a function, which is exactly what the second script looks like

Comment: What's the consequences if no semicolon in this example??

Answer (score 5):

This is just to make sure to `terminate` any previous instruction.

> the semi colon before function invocation is a safety net against
>   concatenated scripts and/or other plugins which may not be closed
>   properly.

https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/jquery-plugin-patterns/extend.html